# What positions exactly did the recently expelled Canadian staff expelled from India hold?

Tags: international-relations, india, canada, diplomatic-immunity, consular-immunity

There have been a lot of rather vague claims about this, e.g. that India revoked "diplomatic immunity" of 41 Canadians, starting from a certain date, resulting in Canada [withdrawing said personnel](https://www.lemonde.fr/en/international/article/2023/10/20/canada-withdraws-41-diplomats-from-india-as-tensions-over-separatist-killing-grow_6189380_4.html), leaving in India "but 21 of Canada's diplomats".

In response, Canada [announced](https://www.canada.ca/en/global-affairs/news/2023/10/statement-on-expulsion-of-canadian-diplomats-by-the-government-of-india.html) that they were suspending in-person services in all their *consulates* in India. (They seem to have 6 such consulates in various Indian cities, not counting the embassy proper.)

But AFAICT [consular immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consular_immunity) is different from the diplomatic one. So, is/are the press [releases] just being sloppy with the distinction? What positions exactly did those 41 expelled Canadians hold? Did they all have *diplomatic* immunity, in the strict sense of the word? Or was it consular immunity for some? Or not even that?

Comment: It's also possible that they were just being imprecise because most people are unaware of the distinction between diplomatic and consular immunity.